# deduping against hbase with high volume data

Tags: multithreading, hbase

I am using hbase to dedupe a high volume stream. I thought it worked well using a unique identifier from each message in the stream to use as a row key. But the end user is still seeing duplicate data from the output stream I create. The only possible cause is duplicate messages getting consumed at the same time.

I have around 50 threads consuming the same  queue which is filled from the stream by a separate process. Is there a way to ensure this does not occur or a more better way to accomplish proper deduping? The process involves doing a GET before inserting a new record.

Answer (score 0):

I see some problems with your approach. If you read stream with 50 threads, there's no way to ensure entry is not present in HBase. There's a possibility that 2 threads will read duplicated message with same id, check HBase, decide that entry is missing and pass messages further.

Duplication check in your concurrent environment can work only with some kind of mutex, and the performance will depend on the duplication frequency, message consume speed and other factors.

I suggest to start with a single thread consumer and try concurrent solution only if you are not satisfied with performance. For a single thread, you can use a hash table for deduplication. Sure it will grow over time, so you'll have to use cache that will expire in a reasonable amount of time depending on the business logic.